# characteristic quadrilateral in region II: wave equation

Tags: partial-differential-equations, wave-equation

> Solve the following problem:
> $$
> \begin{aligned}
> u_{t t} &=u_{x x} \text { for } 0<x<2, t>0 \\
> u(x, 0) &=x(2-x), u_{t}(x, 0)=0 \text { for } 0<x<2 \\
> u(0, t) &=-t^{2}=u(2, t) \text { for } t>0
> \end{aligned}
> $$

Characteristics through the origin and $(2,0)$ divide the strip $0\leq x\leq 2, T\geq 0$ into regions, labeled I, II, III, IV, $\cdots$

[image]

I know how to solve it for region I by using d'Alembert's formula. For region II by parallelogram rule we have
$$
u(x, t)=u(A)+u(B)-u(C)
$$
where $A$ is on the left boundary of the strip, $u(B)$ and $u(C)$ are on the boundary of region I. But I couldn't understand how they get coordinates for $A(0,t_A),B(x_B,t_B)\:\&\:C(x_C,t_C)$ of those points?  It will be a great help if anyone help me to figure out this.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A picture is worth a thousand words

[image: solution]

Can you find out those coordinate now?

> Hint: Use the coordinate $(x,t)$ of $P$ to find out the constant $\alpha,\beta$ and $\gamma$.